# Controller and repository bound to one type- how to use second entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I think I worded the title very poorly.. but here's the problem:

I'm creating an MVC app using EF and have implemented a repository layer to allow me to create unit tests (with the addition of Ninject).

I have simplified the below for the sake of this question and please note I'm extending an existing system and so cannot combine the two.
I have a `Campaign` model

```
public partial class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CampaignDetails CampaignDetail { get; set; }
}

public partial class CampaignDetails
{
    public int CampaignDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? SentOut { get; set; }
    public string SentOutBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
}
```

Every time a campaign is created I also want to create a CampaignDetails` record.

My controller looks like this:

```
    private readonly ICampaignRepository campaignRepository;

    public CampaignController(ICampaignRepository campaignRepository)
    {
        this.campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Campaign campaign)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                campaignRepository.Insert(campaign);
                campaignRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Something went wrong. Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return View(campaign);
    }
```

As you can see it is strongly-typed to use `Campaign`, **so what should I do to then create a `CampaignDetails`?**

Would I have a separate CampaignDetail controller (that has no UI) and repository, and then just call something like `CampaignDetailController.Add(campaign.id)` ?

Or is this where *services* come in handy?

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Campaign campaign,CampaignDetails campaignDetails   )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                //get CampaignDetails  from Http Parameters or seed in some other way
                campaign.CampaignDetails = campaignDetails;
                campaignRepository.Insert(campaign);
                campaignRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Something went wrong. Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return View(campaign);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to just take advantage of the relationship. If you set `campaign.CampaignDetail` to a new instance of `CampaignDetails`, and then save `campaign`, EF will create the `CampaignDetails` record as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is fine.

In your code,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Campaign campaign)
{ 
   ... The rest are the same
}
```

When you pass in campaign, the member 'CampaignDetails' in campaign instance should be populated with data already (that is what you need to do in UI/Javascript layer). So you do not need to pass another parameter for CampaignDetails.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel that combines the Campaign and CampaignDetails.

```
public partial class CampaignModel
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CampaignDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? SentOut { get; set; }
    public string SentOutBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CampaignModel campaignModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Map using AutoMapper or similar library...
                var campaign = Map<Campaign>(campaignModel);
                campaignRepository.Insert(campaign);
                campaignRepository.Save();
                var campaignDetails = New CampaignDetails() { CampaignId = campaign.CampaignId }
                campaignDetailsRepository.Insert(campaign);
                campaignDetailsRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Something went wrong. Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details",new { Id = campaign.CampaignId });
    }
```

For you create view, the Campaign Details would be hidden.  For you read view you could then show the Campaign Details.  Like you suggest I would make a CampaignService and move the database operations there.  Then you can test the CampaignService outside of you MVC project.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with this approach. I've realised something else though, my Campaign controller is injected with the campaignRepository. How do I instantiate campaignDetailRepository? Or if I were to use a service, just inject the service instead of the controller?

Comment: Yes, inject the service.  That way you controller doesn't depend on if you are using your repositories, or DbContext, or Database-first, or Mongo, etc...